# When to use ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if it is a good idea to use ON DELETE CASCADE for example below. This is so I have a general idea when to use ON DELETE CASCADE to delete rows .

**Module Table:**

```
ModuleId (PK) ModuleNo  ModuleName
11            CHI2333    ICT
```

**Course_Module Table:**

```
CourseId  ModuleId (FK)
3          11
```

**Session Table (Exams):**

```
SessionId  SessionName  ModuleId (FK)
5           ASDEE        11
```

In example above, if I delete a row from the `Module` Table, then it will delete rows in the other 2 tables which contains the same ModuleId. In the `Course_Module` Table it determines which course contains which Modules and in the `Session` Table which holds exam details, it will delete any rows (exams) where it contains the deleted ModuleId.

Is it ok to do this for the example above and my general question is that is it wise and normal practice to use ON DELETE CASCADE to delete foreign key rows when the row from the parent table is deleted or remove?

Comment: It depends, if you want to view any historical records for an Course where it had certain past modules although the modulo doesn't exist anymore, then you might want to keep. But if you do not want such analysis information then Parents delete, Children get deleted as well.

Comment: Ah thanks for that information. There could be every chance that a module could be inactivated and reactivated. I could create a boolen to determine this. Thanks

Comment: @user - keep in mind that cascading deletes have some caveats in MySQL.  For example, any `ON DELETE` triggers won't be executed for rows deleted as part of a delete cascade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think its better to have that logic in your code rather than relying on the DB to do the work for you. This is the way I code all my apps.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Perhaps you realise, but this is a pretty controversial statement – it's typically regarded that as much stuff like this as possible should be in the DB layer – then if you access the data through something different to your app then things still work.

Comment: Yes I see your point, however I do a lot of work with SQLCE and its not the best as it does not even support stored proc's so maybe my comment was skewed based on the fact I have to do everything at app level in most of my apps. Either way I think its personal choice to how you approach this, both ways have their pro's and con's.